# How to initialize a two dimensional array using initializer_lists?

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

I've coded this constructor to initialize my two-dimensional array using `initializer_lists`.

```cpp
using namespace std;

class TwoArray{
    int** array;

public:
    TwoArray(initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> list_){
        const size_t row_size = list_.size();
        const size_t column_size = list_.begin()->size();
        
        array = new int[row_size][column_size]{};
    }
};
```

But, this code shows this error:

```sh
main.cpp: In constructor ‘TwoArray::TwoArray(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >)’:
main.cpp:19:48: error: array size in new-expression must be constant
         array = new int[row_size][column_size]{};
                                                ^
main.cpp:19:48: error: the value of ‘column_size’ is not usable in a constant expression
main.cpp:13:22: note: ‘column_size’ was not initialized with a constant expression
         const size_t column_size = list_.begin()->size();
```

And yes, I know that the length of each column may be different, but I've stripped out some code for simplicity. Actually, I am coding a mathematical matrix data structure for C++. And I also know that the two-dimensional array can be treated as one-dimensional and can be initialized easily using one-dimensional `initializer_list`.

How do I bypass this error? And why is this error present here?

Comment: What do you think `new T[n][m]` is doing?

Comment: Evg , I think that ```new T[n][m]``` is allocating a new two-dimensional array of order ```n*m```

Comment: Take a look: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Explanation

Comment: Constructor `TwoArray(initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> list_)` is `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one array of pointers first, then initialize them with arrays of int. Note that this may leak if any allocation throws an exception.

```
array = new int*[row_size];
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[column_size]{};
```

And then analogously `delete` each sub-array.

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < row_size; ++i)
    delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;
```

Although, unless you benefit from owning the memory directly, consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (or `std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]>`) instead.

Comment: Or even better, linear `std::vector<int>` with some index arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

I made this example so you can type:

```
array<int, 2, 3> my_array{ {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}} };
```

Not fully tested yet but it will get you started.
It also shows how you can achieve it without needing "new" or "delete".

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template<typename type_t, size_t COLS, size_t ROWS>
struct array
{
    array(const type_t(&values)[ROWS][COLS])
    {
        for (auto c = 0; c < COLS; ++c)
        {
            for (auto r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r)
            {
                at(c, r) = values[r][c];
            }
        }
    }

    type_t& at(const std::size_t column, const std::size_t row)
    {
        assert(row < m_rows);           // row out of range
        assert(column < m_columns);     // column out of range

        auto index = (row * COLS) + column;
        return m_data[index];
    }

    type_t& operator()(const std::size_t column, const std::size_t row)
    {
        return at(column, row);
    }

private:
    const type_t m_rows{ ROWS };
    const type_t m_columns{ COLS };
    std::array<type_t, ROWS* COLS> m_data{};
};

int main()
{
    array<int, 2, 3> arr{ {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}} };

    assert(arr(1, 1) == 3);
    assert(arr(1, 2) == 5);
}
```